# select rows where id is a part of a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select rows where `id` is a part of a variable:

```
$rx = '1-2-3-4';

$st = $db->query("select id, img from abc where id in ('" . $rx . "') order by date desc");

echo $st->rowCount();  // 1
```

I'm expecting `4` because there are rows where `id` is `2` or `3` or `4`.

Comment: The IN clause uses a comma separated list like `IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` . That said, you should make use of prepared statements. Take a look at mysqli or pdo.

Comment: Where is the source of the data?  User input? Generally untrustworthy source?

Comment: @dnFer, do I need quotes `('1', '2'...)` using prepared statement?

Comment: Using a prepared statement, you'd have `IN (?, ?, ?, ?)` and then bind the placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it by replacing `-` with `','`, note the extra quotes are needed...

```
$st = $db->query("select id, img 
         from abc 
         where id in ('" . str_replace("-", "','", $rx) . "') 
         order by date desc");
```

This generates...

```
select id, img from abc where id in ('1','2','3','4') order by date desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use a prepared statement for security, get the number of rows and iterate the rows of data.

Code (Tested to be successful on localhost)

```
$config = ['localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname'];
$rx = '1-2-3-4';
$values = explode('-', $rx);
$count = sizeof($values);
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, $count, '?'));
$param_types = str_repeat('i', $count);

if (!$conn = new mysqli(...$config)) {
    echo "MySQL Connection Error: <b>Check config values</b>";  // $conn->connect_error
} elseif (!$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, img FROM abc WHERE id IN ($placeholders) ORDER BY `date` DESC")) {
    echo "MySQL Query Syntax Error: <b>Failed to prepare query</b>";  // $conn->error
} elseif (!$stmt->bind_param($param_types, ...$values)) {
    echo "MySQL Query Syntax Error: <b>Failed to bind placeholders and data</b>";  // $stmt->error;
} elseif (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "MySQL Query Syntax Error: <b>Execution of prepared statement failed.</b>";  // $stmt->error;
} elseif (!$result = $stmt->get_result()) {
    echo "MySQL Query Syntax Error: <b>Get Result failed.</b>"; // $stmt->error;
} else {
    $resultset = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo "<div>Numrows: " , sizeof($resultset) , "</div>";
    foreach ($resultset as $row) {
        echo "<div>Row: {$row['id']} & {$row['img']}</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard syntax for searching in a string is comma separated, so you can replace dash with comma:

```
$rx = '1-2-3-4';
$rxc= str_replace("-",",",$rx);

$st = $db->query("select id, img from abc where id in ('" . $rxc . "') order by date desc");

echo $st->rowCount();
```

Comment: quotes are needed

Comment: No. Quotes are NOT needed when dealing with integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by many different way's but I've two ways in my mind. Hope this helps :)

**1.** Try like this way to explode by dash `-` and implode by comma `,`

```
$rx = '1-2-3-4';
$st = $db->query("select id, img from abc where id in ('" . implode(',',explode('-',$rx)) . "') order by date desc");
echo $st->rowCount();  // 1
```

**OR**

**2.** Replace dash `-` with comma `,` using `str_replace('-',',',$rx);`

```
$rx = '1-2-3-4';
$st = $db->query("select id, img from abc where id in ('" . str_replace('-',',',$rx) . "') order by date desc");
echo $st->rowCount();  // 1
```

Comment: quotes are needed

Comment: They are only needed for strings, not integers. With only quotes at the start and end of it, like `IN ('1-2-3-4')`, you are looking for the exact string of `1-2-3-4`, not any of its values or parts of it.

Comment: @blueSky, to me its seem you don't need that, if you still need  then just wrap comma by quotes. Its pretty simple mate.

Comment: specific reason for voting it down?